# How can I create a folder in the root of Laravel directory?

Tags: php, laravel, path

Here is my current directory:

[image]

As you see, I've made a new folder named `classes` in the `app` folder. Also I have some `.php` files *(contains some classes)* in `classes` folder. But I cannot access those classes in my controller. Noted that I add them to my controller like this:

```
use app\classes\Myclassname;
```

But still `My classname` won't be recognized and Laravel trows this:

> Class 'app\classes\Profile' not found

How can I fix mentioned problem?

Comment: Can you show us your `app\classes\Profile`

Comment: did you define the namspace in your `app\classes\Profile`?

Comment: I think you need to capitalize namespace parts to `App\Classes\Profile`

Comment: @xAoc thank you .. the problem was capital `A` in `App` .. problem solved anyway `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Add namespace into your class file, created class file like `app/classes/MyclassnameXXX.php`

```
namespace App\classes;
class MyclassnameXXX {}
```

Now, you have a right to access this class by using the namespace within your classes like:

```
use App\classes\MyclassnameXXX;
```

Hope this work for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can autoload classes using composer like this.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/classes"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

Don't forget to run `composer dump-autoload` to reload classes.

Also, add namespaces to your classes.

```
namespace App\classes;
class MyClass {

}
```

Or, you could use fancy namespaces like Laravel using psr-4 autoloading like this

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "App\\Classes": "app/classes"
    }
},
```